# How can we hide bcc while sending emails in wp7 using c#

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I  want to send email by adding bcc. But i want to hide bcc from the user. Is there any way to achieve this in windows platform using c# coding.

```
EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
            emailcomposer.To = "hello.com";
            emailcomposer.Cc = "info@info.in";
            emailcomposer.Bcc = "hi.com";
            emailcomposer.Subject = "Regards";
            emailcomposer.Body = "Hello Good Morning";
            emailcomposer.Show();
```

Comment: I cannot think of one single, legitimate reason why you should do this. It's not possible, like Matt said already, but could you perhaps clarify why you want to do this? Just curious...

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this.

Doing so would compromise the security principles at the core of the platform as it would allow the recipient of the BCC email to see and gather people's contacts.

The basic security principle is that the app shouldn't be able to do something without the user noticing or specifically requesting it.

Comment: We are working on the X clients project.In the app if user like any deal and if he share it to some of his friends through email, the client want to know which deal he like and share.

Comment: @sunil_divum - the problem is by doing it your way you will also be showing the client the email addresses of the friends he shares with, which is a clear privacy violation if the user does not know about it.